# Optimized binary search

Tags: optimization, binary-search

I have seen  many example of binary search,many method  how to optimize it,so yesterday my lecturer  write code  (in this code let us assume that  first index starts  from 1 and last one is N,so that N is length of array,consider it in pseudo code.code is  like this:

```
L:=1;
R:=N;
while( L<R)
{
m:=div(R+L,2);
 if A[m]> x
{
 L:=m+1;

}
else
{
 R:=m;

}
}
```

Here we assume that array is A,so  lecturer said that we  are not waste time for comparing if element is  at middle part of array every time,also benefit is that  if element is not in array,index says about where it would be located,so it is optimal,is he right?i mean i have seen many kind of binary search from  John Bentley for example(programming  pearls) and so on,and is this code optimal  really?it is written in pascal in my case, but language does not depend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on whether you find the element. If you don't, this will have saved some comparisons. If you could find the element in the first couple of hops, then you've saved the work of all the *later* comparisons and arithmetic. If all the values in the array are distinct, it's obviously fairly unlikely that you hit the right index early on - but if you have broad swathes of the array containing the same values, that changes the maths.

This approach also means you can't narrow the range *quite* as much as you would otherwise - this:

```
R:=m;
```

would normally be

```
R:=m-1;
```

... although that would reasonably rarely make a significant difference.

The important point is that this doesn't change the overall complexity of the algorithm - it's still going to be O(log N).

> also benefit is that if element is not in array,index says about where it would be located

That's true whether you check for equality or not. Every binary search implementation I've seen would give that information.

Comment: so it means that it is optimal and i could use  it in real world  programming right?

Comment: @AleksiBeriashvili: It's more nuanced than that. In some cases it will perform better than alternatives, in some cases it will perform worse. Most platforms have binary search built in though - you don't need to develop it yourself at all.